# Sitecore serialized items with Git autocrlf

Tags: c#, git, serialization, sitecore

We're experiencing a problem with serialized items. Our use case is to work locally with own databases and sync all the items with [Unicorn](https://github.com/kamsar/Unicorn). Then we push all the items to our Git repository. The local Git config is set to `autocrlf=true`. This is needed because we have some frontend engineers on the project which work with Mac OS X. We serialize the complete "core" database with Unicorn (like in the default configuration after installation).

It seems, that some of the items in the core database were created with a non Windows system. If we i.e. look into the item `/sitecore/system/Dictionary/O/One or more items have been changed   Do you want to overwrite these changes`: When I serialize this item and look into it, I see that the `Key` field contains multiple lines and the the line feeds are marked with "`\n`" and that the `content-length` is `77` (see attached screenshot from Notepad++, the left side). After this I push this file to the Git repository and pull the item on another workstation from the repository. Due to the setting `autocrlf=true`, the "`\n`" is automatically converted to a "`\r\n`", which results in a `content-length` of `79` instead of the original `77` (see right side of attached screenshot). When I want to deserialize this item I get the exception that the content-length does not match.

[image]

Does anyone have had such an error before and what did you do to avoid this? I see the option to disable the `autocrlf` or to exclude these items from the serialization sync. But I would like to avoid doing one of these options.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I've never understood the perceived benefits of `autocrlf`. The Win/Lin/Mac angle seems a weak argument, as any halfway decent text editor can handle line endings from other operating systems. `autocrlf` has only ever caused trouble for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can control that behavior from a [.gitattributes](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) file.

In my attributes file, .item files are set to be treated as binary files.

This is the .gitattributes file I use on our projects.

```
* text=auto

# These files are text and should be normalized (convert crlf => lf)
*.cs      text diff=csharp
*.xaml    text
*.csproj  text
*.sln     text
*.tt      text
*.ps1     text
*.cmd     text
*.msbuild text
*.md      text

# TDS files should be treated as binary
*.item -text
```

Comment: This solution works for TDS as well. We ran into major headaches (w/TDS items) when switching to Git for the first time until we learned about this trick.

Comment: The .item files in TDS are just the files from standard sitecore item serialization.